# How to stop a flask video streamer

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I use a flask video streamer and i would like to know how to preform another operation after the streaming has stopped due to the detection of a QRcode. A similar question was asked on stackoverflow and the answer was to use a javascript listener. but giving that what's providing the video stream to the browser is an HTML img element, my question is which Event should the javascript listener be set on.
i've tried several events (abort, error, suspend...) on the image tag but without result.

```
def gen(camera):
while True:
    frame, is_decoded = camera.get_feed() 
    if is_decoded :
        break
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed/')
def video_feed():
    camera = get_camera() 
    return Response(gen(camera),
        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>Camera App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body id="bod">
    <center>
      <div id="camera">     
        <img id="cam" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" alt="video feed">
      </div> 
      <script>
            document.getElementById("cam").addEventListener("abort", function() {
              alert("Hello World!");
            });
      </script>

    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you check `Supported HTML tags:` for [onabort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onabort_media.asp), [onended](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp), [onstalled](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onstalled.asp), [onsuspend](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsuspend.asp) then you see only `<video>` and `<audio>` but not `<img>`. Probably you will have to use JavaScript/AJAX to periodically ask server if QR is detected.

Answer (score 3):

If you check `Supported HTML tags:` for [onabort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onabort_media.asp), [onended](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp), [onstalled](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onstalled.asp), [onsuspend](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsuspend.asp) then you see only `<video>` and `<audio>` but not `<img>`.

Probably you will have to use JavaScript/AJAX to periodically ask server if QR is detected.

---

I found that `<img>` works with `onload` which executes function after every loaded frame. So I use it with `Date()` to remeber when last frame was loaded and I use `setInterval()` to check difference between current time and last frame time to recognize end of stream. I assumed if difference is bigger then 1s then it is end of stream but it is not ideal method because sometimes it may have longer delays between frames but still streaming it. It may have longer delays at the start of page and it may need to run code little later.

In flask I use `self.stop_time` to stop streaming after 3 seconds to emulate end of stream.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, Response
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

class Camera():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.start_time = time.time() 
        self.stop_time = self.start_time + 3
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
        
    def get_feed(self):
        stat, frame = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        
        is_decoded = (time.time() >= self.stop_time) # stop stream after 3 seconds
        
        return jpeg.tobytes(), is_decoded
    
# ---

def get_camera():
    return Camera()
    
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame, is_decoded = camera.get_feed() 
        if is_decoded:
            print('stop stream')
            break
        yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'


@app.route('/video_feed/')
def video_feed():
    camera = get_camera() 
    return Response(gen(camera), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string(
'''<html>
  <body>
      <img id="cam" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
      <script>
            var last_frame_time = ''; // no time before first frame to skip longer delay at start
            
            document.getElementById("cam").addEventListener("load", function() { // event "load" is generated after every loaded frame
                last_frame_time = new Date(); 
            });
            
            var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
                if(last_frame_time != '') { // to 
                    var current_time = new Date();
                    var seconds = (current_time - last_frame_time)/1000;
                    if(seconds >= 1) {
                        alert("Hello World! " + seconds);
                        clearInterval(intervalId);  // stop checking it
                    }
                }
            }, 100);  // 100ms = 0.1s 
      </script>
  </body>
</html>''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

As for me it is better example. It doesn't use `events` but it uses `AJAX` to ask server for `is_decoded` which means end of streaming. It can also get decoded `QR` from server.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, Response, jsonify
import cv2
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

class Camera():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.start_time = time.time() 
        self.stop_time  = self.start_time + 5
        self.is_decoded = False  # keep it to send it with AJAX
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
        
    def get_feed(self):
        stat, frame = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        
        self.is_decoded = (time.time() >= self.stop_time) # stop stream after 5 seconds
        
        return jpeg.tobytes(), self.is_decoded
    
# ---

# create it at start so two functions may use it
camera = Camera()

# send the same camera to two functions
def get_camera():
    return camera
    
def gen(camera):
    # start timer only when start streaming
    camera.start_time = time.time()
    camera.stop_time = camera.start_time + 5
    
    while True:
        frame, is_decoded = camera.get_feed() 
        if is_decoded:
            print('stop stream')
            break
        yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n'

@app.route('/video_feed/')
def video_feed():
    camera = get_camera() 
    return Response(gen(camera), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/is_decoded/')
def is_decoded():
    camera = get_camera() 
    return jsonify({'is_decoded': camera.is_decoded})

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string(
'''<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <img id="cam" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
      <script>
            var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(){
                $.getJSON('/is_decoded/', function(data){
                    if(data['is_decoded'] == true) {
                        alert("Hello World! " + data['is_decoded']);
                        clearInterval(intervalId);  // stop checking it
                    };
                })
            }, 500);  // 500ms = 0.5s 
      </script>
  </body>
</html>''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

**BTW:**

As I understand you want to detect `QRcode` on image from user's web camera - but `cv2` can works only with local camera and it will not work if someone else will use page remotly. It would need JavaScript to get image from his camera, send it to server and process.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer, I have no experience with AJAX so that oppened a whole new approach to discover. Your last note was extremely pertinent, it is indeed my intention to detect the code from the user's webcam and i felt a bit stupid for missing such a detail.